# How to inactivate a validate rule using SFDX command

Tags: salesforcedx, validation-rule, sfdx-plugin, ci, cicd

Is there any way that we can inactive/deactivate a validation rule using SFDX command?
I have researched completely. And I thought that `force:source:deploy` would help, but it seems to be a little complicated.

The reason why I am asking this is that I have automation that works if the validation rule is inactive.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a command to disable a Validation Rule. What you would need to do is

1. If your local project does not already contain the Validation Rule metadata, retrieve it (using, for example, `sfdx force:source:retrieve`).
2. Alter the [metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_validationformulas.htm) for the Validation Rule to set the `active` tag to `false`.
3. Re-deploy your metadata, using, for example, `sfdx force:source:deploy`. Note that this will deploy all of the metadata in your local project, which could overwrite other changes in your org if you have not retrieved them.